# Bson does not serialize with 'new' overridden attributes and reports duplicate use of a propertyname

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

We want to use a model that has a public variant and a local variant. We want to save it in a mongo database and want to be able to read (deserialize) it in the local or the public variant. Whatever is needed at some point in time.

In order to do so we must assure we save it with exact same property names. To ease this process we create the private model by extending the public model with additional properties. If we use the newtonsoft json serializers this works like a charm. However with the Bson serializers this does not work. The reason is probably that the keyword 'new' is not recognized in the property definition

```
namespace Public
{
   [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    class Job
    {
        public Payment Payment { get; set; }
    }

    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    class Payment
    {
        public long Reference { get; set; }
    }   
}

namespace Private
{
    class Job : Public.Job
    {
        public new Payment Payment     { get; set; }
        public string      PrivateData { get; set; }
    }

    class Payment : Public.Payment
    {
        public string PrivateData { get; set; }
    }   
}


// Calling code returns MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException:
// 'The property 'Payment' of type 'Public.Job' cannot use element name
// 'Payment' because it is already being used by property 'Payment' of type
// 'Private.Job'.'
var test = job.ToBson();
```

If I perform a Json serialize there is no problem as the Json serializer correctly recognizes the override of Payment by the keyword 'new'.

Does anyone know a solution. Beside coding the classes without inheritence, which will probably work but that is bad coding practice. Please help! It looks like the reflection inside the driver misses the 'new' keyword, but how to work around it?

Comment: Shadowing is generally bad idea... so not very surprising that you get unexpected result when you use it (Also "classes without inherentance … is bad coding practice" is very controversial statement... There are a lot of people who would say "prefer composition over inheritance"...)

Comment: Member hiding/shadowing is not some form of overriding. It is entirely different. Thinking overriding and hiding are kind of the same is a mistake and using member hiding hapazardly in your code can really quickly ruin your day, as you have just experienced. Coincidentally, another SO user a few hours ago kinda fell for the same mistake of thinking overriding and hiding are kinda the same (you are by far not alone in making this mistake). If you are interested, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068661/real-benefit-of-virtual-keyword

Comment: Ok admitting hiding the underlying class can be dangerous but because the deseriliazation must/will use the same name I see no other means of accomplishing that by hiding the public member. but it would make my day if I could use this model, copying the same data to another class is definitly more error prone. The private model must have all properties of the public model. So how would you guys, being the software purists, solve my problem and make my day ?

Comment: Well, according to your statement "_To ease this process we create the private model by extending the public model with additional properties._" i understand you do not intend to replace properties of your Public.Job model, but only add additional properties to your Private.Job model. Private.Job model **inherits** from Public.Job, that includes inheriting the properties of Public.Job. Thus, Private.Job doesn't need to redeclare the properties inherited from Public.Job...

Comment: I agree this would work for the Job class, but this will not work for the payment class, Note that the private payment class has an additional property in this sample. So the payment that is refered to in the private job has to be the "private.payment". Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Ah, i overlooked that part. I don't know about MongoDB.Bson serializer, but would it perhaps be possible to tell the serializer in some way to ignore the Public.Job.Payment property or use a custom serializer/serialization method to produce the desired serialization result?

Comment: The Newtonsoft Json serializer can serialize/deserialize this without problems. I was hoping the Bson driver writers would read this post and fix this. I'm sure this can be solved with proper reflection use. As my reallife classes are much more complex, writing a special serializer would be a maintenance nightmare. In fact this seems a bug..